# setuptools application fails to find package functions after setup.py install, yet works for setup.py develop

Tags: python, setuptools

Im struggling to run my app after using setuptools `python setup.py install`. I get a failed import error, `ImportError: cannot import name 'db'` despite the variable being in the correct module. When I print `dir(package)` I get the output:
`['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`
As if the variable is not in the file at all. However when I run `python setup.py develop` the application works fine, and the same print returns:
`['Account', 'Constants', 'SQLAlchemy', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'current_app', 'db', 'requests', 'take_snapshot']`
Showing the missing variable.

My full setup.py files looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='accountService',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'certifi==2017.11.5',
        'chardet==3.0.4',
        'click==6.7',
        'Flask==0.12.2',
        'Flask-API==1.0',
        'Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2',
        'Flask-Testing==0.7.1',
        'idna==2.6',
        'itsdangerous==0.24',
        'Jinja2==2.10',
        'MarkupSafe==1.0',
        'requests==2.18.4',
        'SQLAlchemy==1.1.15',
        'urllib3==1.22',
        'Werkzeug==0.13',
    ],
    setup_requires=[
        'pytest-runner'
    ],
    tests_require=[
        'pytest'
    ],
)
```

My egg SOURCES.txt is:

```
README.md
setup.cfg
setup.py
accountService/__init__.py
accountService/factory.py
accountService/run_app.py
accountService.egg-info/PKG-INFO
accountService.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
accountService.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
accountService.egg-info/requires.txt
accountService.egg-info/top_level.txt
accountService/blueprints/__init__.py
accountService/blueprints/accountService.py
accountService/eventSourcing/__init__.py
accountService/eventSourcing/aggregates.py
accountService/eventSourcing/commands.py
accountService/eventSourcing/events.py
accountService/eventSourcing/handlers.py
accountService/eventSourcing/util.py
tests/__init__.py
tests/test_account_service.py
tests/util.py
```

Comment: could you include the import statement that is generating the error?

Comment: Don't pin versions in `install_requires`.

Comment: @Sebastian the import statement is `from accountService.eventSourcing.aggregates import db`

Comment: Dont know if this helps but I have the same issue with `pip install --editable .` vs just `pip install .`